# How to make tornado call itself asynchronously

Tags: python, tornado

Below is the simple hello world app.  How can I have tornado call '/' in two threads with a 1 sec sleep.  Thus the page will be called 2 times per second.  I will need later to extend to a redis call but want to start simple now since I am new to this logic.  I need to build a web page that is called repeatably asynchronously.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8880)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to `tornado`, check out [tornadogist](http://tornadogists.org/2185380/). They have a lot of useful code snippets. Here is one adapted to your need:

```
from time import sleep
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, asynchronous, RequestHandler
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# 2 threads
_workers = ThreadPool(2)

def run_background(func, callback, args=(), kwds={}):
    def _callback(result):
        IOLoop.instance().add_callback(lambda: callback(result))
    _workers.apply_async(func, args, kwds, _callback)

# blocking task like querying to MySQL
def blocking_task(n):
    sleep(n)
    return n

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        run_background(blocking_task, self.on_complete, (1,))

    def on_complete(self, res):
        self.write("Test {0}<br/>".format(res))
        self.finish()

HTTPServer(Application([("/", MainHandler)],debug=True)).listen(8888)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Does not look look like its calling its self when i run the code.